# Login information and password confirmation not working c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, passwords, registration

I am trying to make a user registration type of program. I want the user to register entering login, password and confirm password. Then, after that is done and they choose an option in the main menu, I would like the user to login, by validating their details (login and password). So far I have each thing in two functions, but for some reason when they type in the password to login, even if the passwords match, the program gives out "incorrect password" message:

```
string login_information(string login, string set_password, string confirm_password)
{

cout<<"Please enter the login: ";
cin>>login;
cout<<"Please create your password: ";
cin>>set_password;
cout<<"Please confirm password: ";
cin>>confirm_password;
while (set_password!=confirm_password)
{
    cout<<"passwords do not match"<<endl<<"Please confirm password: ";
    cin>>confirm_password;
}
if (set_password==confirm_password)
    cout<<"Registration complete"<<endl;    
system("pause");
system("CLS");
return confirm_password;
}

void password_protection(string confirm_password, string password_input)
{
cin >> password_input;
while (password_input!=confirm_password)
{
    cout << "Incorrect password, please re-enter password: "<<endl;
    cin>>password_input;
}
if (password_input==confirm_password)
    cout<<"Authorised."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a global variable `confirm_password`? Because the parameter to `password_protection` is not spelled like that.

Comment: @BoPersson, yes, sorry, i do. Just a typo here. Sorry about that, edited.Still displays the "incorrect password"message though

Comment: In that case, are you sure you save the return value from `login_information` and pass that to `password_protection`?

Comment: @BoPersson, no, that i am not sure of. How can i do that?